# Find documents where same field value is found in any outer or nested fields

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch has an index where _source is of schema

```
{
  ...
  "color" : "white",
  "items" : [
    {
      ...
      "color": "blue",
      "items": [...]
    },
    {
      ...
      "color": "red",
      "items": [...]
    },
    {
      ...
      "color": "green",
      "items": [...]
    }
  ]
},
```

The query needs to find the documents where `{"color" : "red"}` in any of the nested fields, it is **not** given that "color" is present in only "items", it could exits in any outer or deeply nested fields of the document.
so basically the query needs to find `{"color" : "red"}` anywhere in the document

Query I could come up with using the "nested" from the documentation

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "*",
      "query" : {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {"match": {"*.color": "red"}}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }  

}
```

and using query_string

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "*",
      "query": {
        "query_stirng": {
          "query": "red",
          "default_field": "color"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

however these queries are yielding the desired result

Comment: Are you using a nested mapping for other reasons? Because, if you were not using nested, you could do a `multi_match` and query the field `*color`.

Answer (score 0):

## Way #1. Manual Explicit Query

For sample mapping

```
PUT /nested_colors
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "color": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "level1": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "color": {
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "level2": {
                        "type": "nested",
                        "properties": {
                            "color": {
                                "type": "text"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and documents

```
PUT /nested_colors/_bulk
{"create":{"_id":1}}
{"color":"red"}
{"create":{"_id":2}}
{"level1":[{"color":"red"}]}
{"create":{"_id":3}}
{"level1":[{"level2":[{"color":"red"}]}]}
```

write such query or kind of

```
GET /nested_colors/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "color": "red"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "level1",
                        "query": {
                            "match": {
                                "level1.color": "red"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "level1",
                        "query": {
                            "nested": {
                                "path": "level1.level2",
                                "query": {
                                    "match": {
                                        "level1.level2.color": "red"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Response

```
{
    "took" : 1,
    "timed_out" : false,
    "_shards" : {
        "total" : 1,
        "successful" : 1,
        "skipped" : 0,
        "failed" : 0
    },
    "hits" : {
        "total" : {
            "value" : 3,
            "relation" : "eq"
        },
        "max_score" : 0.2876821,
        "hits" : [
            {
                "_index" : "nested_colors",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "1",
                "_score" : 0.2876821,
                "_source" : {
                    "color" : "red"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index" : "nested_colors",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "2",
                "_score" : 0.2876821,
                "_source" : {
                    "level1" : [
                        {
                            "color" : "red"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "_index" : "nested_colors",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "3",
                "_score" : 0.2876821,
                "_source" : {
                    "level1" : [
                        {
                            "level2" : [
                                {
                                    "color" : "red"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

## Way #2. Automatic Script

You can write a script passing through all fields and comparing values

## Way #3. Re-organize Your Data

It's strange for me that there are fields of the same name with different depth. Think of re-organizing your data. It makes your query simpler